# How to configure package-file path for Azure release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-artifacts, azure-batch

I was following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-ci-cd) from Microsoft to use Azure pipeline for build and release. Reached upto [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thPTT.png) section and confused about the following code:

```
az batch application package create --application-id $(batchApplicationId) 

--name $(batchAccountName) 

--resource-group $(resourceGroupName) 

--version $(batchApplicationVersion) 

--package-file=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.Artifacts.{YourBuildArtifactSourceAlias}.BuildId).zip
```

I have configured the following in pipeline variables:

- **batchApplicationId**
- **batchAccountName**
- **resourceGroupName**
- **batchApplicationVersion**

The only thing remaning is configuring the **package-file**

As far as I understand, I just have to replace **YourBuildArtifactSourceAlias** with my artifact source alias, and I have done that. But when deploying the release pipeline, I get the following error:

```
.zip was unexpected at this time. 
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 255
```

As we can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJxS.png), the only failing part of this whole process is when uploading the package to the application created, which is the final step.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the = between --package-file and the path with a space? Might be that the article has a typo? `--package-file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.Artifacts.{YourBuildArtifactSourceAlias}.BuildId).zip`

Comment: @j-petty Hi, I just tried what you suggested but still getting the same error :(

Comment: add a simple "commandline" task and do `echo $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.Artifacts.{YourBuildArtifactSourceAlias}.BuildId).zip` inside. I suspect there's something wrong with the path - maybe some variable isn't expanded, or there's space somewhere. You can also try using `$(Build.BuildId)` instead of `$(Release.Artifacts.xxx)`, that should be the [same thing for the primary artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---primary-artifact)

Comment: Please list all files in that folder `ls $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. It should help you figure out.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried configuring by following the methods you both advised and was able to get it running. Like qbik mentioned, instead of $(Release.Artifacts.xxx), I put $(Build.BuildId), and like Krzysztof Madej mentioned, I listed all the folders and subfolders and configured the path that way. Thanks so much!